# Can multi job Spring Batch app load minimum set of beans?

Tags: spring-batch

My app defines `Jobs` *A* and *B*. When the time comes for *A* to be run, all beans are loaded, including the ones for *B* (and viceversa). I'd prefer this not to be the case, can it be achieved?

Comment: I think it should, I knew of lazy bean init but was hoping for an all-lazy-init flag, which is exactly what you posted! I agree with you, ideally each job should be packaged separately, alas that's not an option. Thanks!

Comment: If packaging each job separately is not an option, then using a Spring profile is the way to go.

Comment: How would the profile be set at runtime?

Comment: Why do you need to set it (or reset it) at runtime? How do you package and run your jobs?

Comment: When the job runner runs a job, how does it set the right profile so that only a subset of the beans are loaded?

Comment: Spring profiles are applied at application startup to select which beans to load in the application context. When running the job, the `Job` and `JobLauncher` beans have beans are already created so it is too late to select a profile at this time. Again, why do you need to set it (or reset it) at runtime? How do you package and run your jobs? Do you load all your jobs in a single JVM running 24/7?

Comment: I understand, sorry, the question was around at what point do you specify the profile you're interested in for a particular Job. We're using Spring Cloud Data Flow, am I wrong to say you specify -Pmy-profile at the point of launching the job from Spring Cloud Data Flow?